# "Maximum call stack size exceeded" at a quicksort algorithm in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, sorting, quicksort

I am currently working on some sorting algorithms but I got stuck at my quicksort algorithm.

Exact error:

> quicksort.js:25 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
> at quicksort (quicksort.js:25)
> at quicksort (quicksort.js:27)
> at quicksort (quicksort.js:27)
> at quicksort (quicksort.js:27)
> at quicksort (quicksort.js:27)
> at quicksort (quicksort.js:27)
> at quicksort (quicksort.js:27)
> at quicksort (quicksort.js:27)
> at quicksort (quicksort.js:27)
> at quicksort (quicksort.js:27)

Code:

```
function quicksort(array, left, right) {
    if (array.length > 1) {
        let sort = quicksortChange(array, left, right); //line 25
        if (left < sort - 1) {
            quicksort(array, left, sort - 1); //line 27
        }
        if (right > sort) {
            quicksort(array, sort, right);
        }
    }
    return array;
}


function quicksortChange(array, left, right) {
    let pivot_number = Math.floor(array.length / 2);
    let pivot = array[pivot_number];
    for (i = 0; i < pivot_number; i++) {
        if (array[i] > pivot) {
            let a = array[i];
            for (j = array.length - 1; j > pivot; j--) {
                if (array[j] < pivot) {
                    let b = array[j];
                    if (a <= b) {
                        array[i] = b;
                        array[j] = a;
                        i++
                        j--
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```

You start the algorithm with:

```
let cleanArray = quicksort(array, 0, array.length - 1)
```

Comment: What’s the end condition? I only see a check for the array having no elements, but the array seems to be passed through with no changes?

Comment: you are always passing the same array, thus `array.length` will never decrease and you  have an infinite recursion ..

Comment: `quicksortChange` doesn't appear to use its `left` or `right` parameters.

Comment: @RaymondChen Yes, I see. My bad. But there is still the same problem. Any idea how I can fix the problem with the recursion?

Comment: Use the `left` and `right` parameters to control the partition. Right now, you're partitioning the entire array, so every recursion just starts the problem over from scratch and you never finish.

Comment: @evolutionxbox the if conditions are used to check if the right and left side have the same size. I just started coding about 2 months, so I am also open to better versions.

Comment: @derpirscher I do not think the recursion is infinite. If both of the if-conditions are passed in function quicksort, there is no recursion left.

Comment: @Raymond Chen Oh that is right! I would never see this. Thanks a Lot!

Comment: @juWind: In `quicksortChange` you are doing `let pivot_number = Math.floor(array.length / 2);`, and in the end return `i` (which will be `pivot_number`). As you are always using `array.length` , `pivot_number` will always be the same. Then you do `if (left < sort - 1)` (where `sort === pivot_number`). And as `left` is initialized with `0` this condition will always be `true` thus you have an infinite recursion ...

Answer (score 0):

Example of quicksort using classic Hoare partition algorithm:

```js
function quicksort(array, left, right) {
    if(left >= right)
        return;
    var pivot = array[Math.floor((left + right) / 2)];
    var i = left - 1;
    var j = right + 1;
    while (true){
            while (array[++i] < pivot);
            while (array[--j] > pivot);
            if (i >= j)
                break;
            var t = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = t;
        }
    quicksort(a, left, j);
    quicksort(a, j+1, right);
}

var a = new Array(1000)
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i] = parseInt(Math.random() * 1000000000)
}
console.time('measure')
quicksort(a, 0, a.length-1)
console.timeEnd('measure')
for (var i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
    if(a[i-1] > a[i]){
        console.log('error')
        break
    }
}
```